# Why Hashset doesn't take duplicate values?

Tags: java

I have a doubt regarding hashset. Why doesn't Hashset take duplicate elements? I know it implements Set interface and places the values in a hashtable. What I mean is what may be the code internally written for not taking duplicate values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some information about it

[Collision Resolution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table#Collision_resolution)

[And here is the source](http://developer.classpath.org/doc/java/util/Hashtable-source.html)

Answer (score 7):

Precisely for the reason you mentioned, a `HashSet` implements the `Set` interface:

**Set**

> A collection that contains no
>   duplicate elements. More formally,
>   sets contain no pair of elements e1
>   and e2 such that e1.equals(e2), and at
>   most one null element. As implied by
>   its name, this interface models the
>   mathematical set abstraction.

You want duplicates? Use `List`.

Comment: If he's using a custom datatype, he could override the `hashCode()` to return different values for similar instances (though its unconventional)....will still work with `Set`

Comment: @st0le, what do you mean similiar instances?  you mean instances that should under normal circumstances be equal?  If so, then you're setting yourself up for huge bugs in your program if you also override the equals method, which you should.

Comment: of course, that's what i meant...not exactly the best way. :P

Answer (score 0):

Because, by definition, a set is a thing that does not contain duplicates.

Answer (score -2):

HashSet does not allows duplicate values, why because HashSet Class contain add() method, it will check before while adding elements inside HashSet. if we are trying adding duplicate values it returns false, so not allowed.

here  present, e both are equal returns false.`Object PRESENT;
   public boolean add(E e) {
    return map.put(e, PRESENT)==null;
    }`